# How do I divide the sum of one column by the sum of another column when they are from different tables in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to grab the sum of two identically named columns, except they are from two different tables (I have been told to combine them multiple times, unfortunately I do not have a choice in the matter...). I want to then divide these two summed values to find the percentage variation.

Below is the code I wrote, all it does is load infinitely.

```
SELECT SUM(C.[Market Value]) AS CSUM, 
       SUM(P.[Market Value]) AS PSUM, 
       CSUM/PSUM AS Percentage_Variation
FROM JanReport AS P,
     FebReport AS C;
```

I have been unsuccessful in using `UNION` and `JOIN`. It seems like this function should be easily doable, as I have been able to sum and find % variation by asset class, I can even get the sum of both columns to show with the Totals function. However I just cannot seem to get them to divide.

Code that worked:

```
SELECT  SUM(FebReport.[Market Value]) AS Curr_Total_MV,
(
SELECT SUM(JanReport.[Market Value]) FROM JanReport
) AS Prior_Total_MV,
SUM(FebReport.[Market Value]) / 
(
SELECT SUM([Market Value]) FROM JanReport
) AS Percentage_Variation_In_Total_MV,
IIf(
0.9<Percentage_Variation_In_Total_MV AND 
Percentage_Variation_In_Total_MV<1.1,'Pass','Fail') AS Result
FROM FebReport;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline `SELECT` should work here:

```
SELECT SUM([Market Value]) / (SELECT SUM([Market Value]) FROM JanReport) AS Percentage_Variation, 
FROM FebReport;
```

**Update**: Two sub-queries each returning just one row can be cross-joined to provide the underlying values:

```
SELECT
    [Current Market Value],
    [Previous Market Value],
    [Current Market Value] / [Previous Market Value] As Percentage_Variation
FROM
    (SELECT SUM([Market Value]) As [Current Market Value]  FROM FebReport) AS C,
    (SELECT SUM([Market Value]) As [Previous Market Value] FROM JanReport) AS P;
```

Comment: Works well. Thank you. Is there any way to include the sum of P.[Market Value] and sum of C.[Market Value] in the Select statement?

Comment: Oh wow @Y.B. you answer so fast...I have already written something (in main post). Will look at yours as it seems way more simple!

Comment: That was just by chance. You code is fine though it might end up calculating SUM over JanReport twice thus impairing performance and it might be tricky to support having to remember two places to change the source table name.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am pretty terrible at naming of tables. I learn everything on the go and have picked up so many bad habits from other peoples bad habits...

I really like your formatting so I will be taking that.

Comment: Not at all. One more tip: watch out for "division by zero" when JanReport is empty. :-)